# Start and Pause Interval onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, setinterval

I am trying to start an interval on ready, then pause it on click, and resume where I left off.  I have everything down but the 'resume' part.  Can I get a little help?

Here's my fiddle:  [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cearnhart/86YET/)

HTML:

```
<a href="questions_create.asp?interactive=off" class="start"><img src='Icons/control_stop.png'  width='16' height='16' border='0' /></a>

<span id="Stop" style="cursor:pointer;display:none;" class="pauseit tutorialLoop" value="stop"><img src='http://examsoftdemo.com/Icons/control_pause.png' width='16' height='16' border='0' /></span>

<span id="Start" style="cursor:pointer;" class="playit tutorialLoop" value="start"><img src='http://examsoftdemo.com/Icons/control_play.png' width='16' height='16' border='0' /></span>
```

JS:

```
 function fadeLoop() {  //start the interval loop
        var counter = 0,
            divs = $('.fader').css('visibility', 'visible').hide(),
            dur = 100;  // animate

        function showDiv() {  // show divs in order
            divs.fadeOut(dur) // hide all divs
            .filter(function (index) {
                return index == counter % divs.length;
            }) // figure out correct div to show
            .delay(dur) // delay until fadeout is finished
            .fadeIn(dur, function () {
                $(this).focus();
            }); // and show it
            counter++;
        }; // function to loop through divs and show correct div
        showDiv(); // show first div    
        return setInterval(function () {
            showDiv(); // show next div
        }, 2 * 1000); // do this every 2 seconds    
    };
    var interval = null,
        counter = 0;

    $(".playit").on('click', function (e) {  // play the interval loop
        // e.stopPropagation();
        if (!interval) {
            interval = fadeLoop();
            counter = counter + 1;
            $(".tutorialLoop").val(counter);
        }
    });
    $(".pauseit").on('click', function (e) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = null
        //$(this).val("Start");
        //interval = undefined;
    });
    $(".playit").click();  // simulate start
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two counter variables, one is global, one is limited to the fadeLoop function.  The global one is only used for:

`$(".tutorialLoop").val(counter);`

while the one in fadeLoop is used for the messages, and gets reset to 0 every time the play button is clicked.  Instead, remove the one in fadeLoop, and only use the global one.

Also, it looks like the loop picks up on the div AFTER the current one, so you may want to `-= 1` to make it stay consistent (although this may not be your desired behavior).

So the final code may look something like:

```
function fadeLoop() {    
    var divs = $('.fader').css('visibility','visible').hide(),
        dur = 100;           

        function showDiv() {
            //...
        }; // function to loop through divs and show correct div

        showDiv(); // show first div    

        return setInterval(function() {
            showDiv(); // show next div
        }, 2 * 1000); // do this every 5 seconds    
     };

     var interval = null,
        counter = 0;
        interval

     $(".playit").on('click' , function(e) {
        if (!interval){
            counter -= 1;
            interval = fadeLoop();

            $(".tutorialLoop").val(counter);
        }
     });    

    $(".pauseit").on ('click' , function(e) {
            clearInterval(interval);
           interval = null
    });

    $(".playit").click();
});
```